# SELECT spcific rows which connected with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to pick up the data from `Company` table

The easiest way is like this

```
"Select id from Company "

Company Table
id company
1   comA 
2   comB
3   comC
```

However I have another table `Member Table` which is connected with `Company Table` via company_id

```
Member Table
id  company_id companymember
1   1          john
2   1          Tam
3   2          haya
4   1          lee
5   3          kih
6   3          wild
```

Now I would like to pick "companys which have more than two members"

(In this case  `comA` and `comC` has two members)

How can I make it by SQL??

Comment: `Group by company_id having count(companymember) > 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`

```
select company, count(*)
from Company a
inner join member b on a._id = b.company_id
group by company
having count(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  Company.company, count(*) 
FROM
  Company 
JOIN 
  Member on Company.id = Member.company_id 
GROUP BY 
  Company.company 
HAVING 
  count(*) > 2
```